# Display a List from Subsite on a Modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, modern-pages, spo

It there a way for me to display a list from a subsite on a Modern page?

- Home (want the list to appear here)

  - Subsite

    - List

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Enable **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature in **Site collection features**

[image]

2.Enable **SharePoint Server Publishing** feature in **Manage site features**

[image]

3.Go to Site Settings page, click on "**Navigation**" in the "**Look and Feel**" section

4.On the Navigation Settings page, scroll to **Global Navigation** section, select "**Structural Navigation**" option.

5.On the Navigation Settings page, scroll to **Current Navigation** section, select "**Structural Navigation**" option and check "**Show subsites**" and "**Show pages**" checkbox

[image]

[image]